# Select with when and sum

Tags: sql, case

i have table Match and i need sum of goals. If `Match.Home_team='Tupesy'` I need sum of `Match.Home_team='Tupesy'`, else `sum` of `Match.Away_goals`.

Now i have this, but is totally wrong :/

```
SELECT *,
    CASE (Match.Home_team)
        WHEN (Match.Home_team='Tupesy')THEN (SUM(Match.Home_goals))
        ELSE (SUM(Match.Away_goals))
        END
FROM Match
Where (Match.ID_match='1');
```

Comment: can you please elaborate with your current output and expected output?

Comment: Can you provide the table structure? What is ID_Match here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be like that (SUM and CASE should be written in reversed order):

```
select Sum(case
             when (Home_Team = 'Tupesy') then
               Home_goals
             else 
               Away_goals 
           end)
  from Match
 where (ID_match = '1')
```